# fancybox link works on first but not the other

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a div containing blog posts which link to the post, I want to display the linked page in a modal and thought fancybox, I have it working but only on the first link you click.

http://bit.ly/issi7j

I'm not really sure why this would happen. And to make matters worse it works perfectly in safari. I haven't checked IE, this is a provisional test to see if Fancybox is the right modal plugin to use.

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".blog-post h2.post-title a").addClass("fancy").fancybox({
                'width': 600,
                'height': 620,
                'autoDimensions':false,
                'autoScale':false
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

I haven't really came across this before so any help is greatly appreciated and if I get the answer I will post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be the wrapped `$(window).load(function(){..});`, remove that and try again.

**EDIT:** Error occured due to JS script conflict when loading a full page into the fancybox modal. Loading the modal pages as iFrames fixes the issue.

Comment: I notice you're loading a full page in the modal and that page includes a lot of JS. There could be a conflict there. Try loading it as an iFrame `type: 'iframe'`.